# How do I see my added adapter on the /etc/network/interfaces file?

Tags: interface, vmware-workstation

I just added 2 additional network adapters on VMware workstation but i can't see them on the `/etc/network/interfaces` file to edit them.

What should I do to have these new interfaces listed on the network interface file?

Answer (score 1):

The only entries that automagically appear in `/etc/network/interfaces` are those detected during installation. Otherwise, you'll have to add those yourself, manually, with whatever configuration you need.